# Background color doesn't change permanently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color when a button is clicked. But, when the button is clicked, it changes color for a second and it goes back to the original color which is set at the beginning of the page.

How can I set the color permanently?

Javascript:

```js
function setbackground(color)
{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input id="bigbutton" type="submit" value=""
  style="background: url(moods/rocking.png) no-repeat center" 
  onclick="setbackground('#B84DB8')"/>
```

Comment: You're using a submit button, which is causing the page to be submitted back to the server and then re-loaded.

Comment: swap the <input> with <button> and remove the "type".

Comment: @Geoffrey — The default `type` of a `<button>` element is `submit`, so that won't help.

Comment: my bad.. set the button type="button" - it's still clickable, it just doesn't submit.

Comment: are you trying to submit a form? and then change bg color?

Comment: yeap. I need to submit a form and then change bg color

Answer (score 2):

Changing the DOM changes the current page.

Clicking a submit button will submit the form it is in.

Submitting a form will load a new (although possibly identical) page from the server (which won't preserve local DOM changes).

So you are changing the current page, then immediately throwing it away and loading a clean one.

---

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you can:

- Prevent the submission of the form with the JavaScript (the usual way if you are using an `onclick` attribute is to `return false`, but we prefer `addEventListener` to `onclick` attributes these days). If you are going to do that unconditionally, you might question why you are using a submit button (rather then a regular button) in the first place (although [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is cool).
- Use the name/value of the submit button to cause the server to generate a different HTML document (with the colours you want) instead of using JS
- Store the data about the colour change locally (e.g. in a cookie or localStorage) and have JS read that when the document loads and repeat the change.

---

From a comment:

> yeap. I need to submit a form and then change bg color

Then the first option won't work with (unless you also complicate matters with Ajax).

Using server side code to make the change would be the least intrusive approach.